# I want to refresh my ListView's item where items are dynamic

Tags: android

I want to refresh my `ListView` item where item comes from server. I used `notifyDataSetChanged();` but it is not working for my code. I need when I pressed back `button` the `ListView` should be refresh.

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.declined_list_view_layout, null, true);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);
    textViewName.setText( ages[position]+" years"+" , "+heights[position]+" cm"+", "+communities[position]+" : "+castes[position]+" , "+educations[position]+" , "+occupations[position]+" , "+incomes[position]+", "+locations[position]);

    Button btnSort =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
    btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"shortlist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Button btnChat =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnchat);
    btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), BlankActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ids[position], 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i.putExtra("id", ids[position]);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    return listViewItem;
}
```

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged() where you are getting data form server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())**

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

**I need when I pressed back button the ListView should be refresh**

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapterOBJ.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

> **[onResume()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onresume)**- When the activity enters the Resumed state, it comes to the
>   foreground, and then the system invokes the onResume() callback. This
>   is the state in which the app interacts with the user.

Comment: @VikasGodiyal Glad to hear.

Answer (score 3):

Dont call notify in getView, since this will be rendered for each item for the list. Instead this should generally be done, once you have the entire data fetched from the server to refresh it once.

if you want to refresh when you press back button, add the notifyDataSetChangedMethod in Activity life cycle method. You can add it in onResume as well as.

add this inside onResume should do the trick for you.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: no problem. Glad its working for you. Happy coding. :)

Comment: @NikitPrabhu Well Elaborate .